# Tool to get full qualified type name

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a tool that can get the full qualified name from types in assembly?

i know how to construct the full qualified name, but i need something that loads the assembly like reflector for example and take the fullqualified name from their types.

Comment: You can use reflection, that's where Reflector gets its name.

Comment: Assembly.GetTypes() does not fit your requirements ?

Comment: i used to use reflector but it's not for free anymore, now i'm using reflector 6 and it doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 4):

`Assembly.Load("YourAssemblyName").GetTypes().Select(t => t.AssemblyQualifiedName)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var types = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\work\Foo.dll").GetTypes();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }
    }
}
```